# How do I Override UnmarshalJSON Correctly?

Tags: go

I am trying to write a simple custom marshaler and failing. Notice I have an interface that has three functions. Both `Happy` and `Sad` structs implement this interface by embedding the `emotion` struct which implements all the three required functions.

The problem is `UnmarshalJSON` does not get invoked when I call `json.Unmarshal()` on the pointer to either `Happy` or `Sad` and I can't understand why. You can reproduce the exact codebase in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GB2RI4pMLSz) or just look below. You will notice that while `MarshalJSON` is correctly called, `UnmarshalJSON` isn't.

```
type Emotion interface {
    String() string
    MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
    UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error 
}

type emotion struct {
    status string
}

func (s emotion) String() string {
    return s.status
}

func (s emotion) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        fmt.Println("MarshalJSON is overriden: I am called fine")
    x := struct {
        Status string
    }{
        Status: s.String(),
    }

    return json.Marshal(x)
}

func (s *emotion) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
        fmt.Println("MarshalJSON is overriden: I am never called")
    y := struct {
        Status string
    }{
        Status: "",
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &y)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    s.status = y.Status
    return nil
}

type Happy struct {
    *emotion
}

// Job is not in any detention
type Sad struct {
    *emotion
}


func main() {
    x := Happy{&emotion{status: "happy"}}
    jsonX, _ := json.Marshal(x)
    var y Emotion
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonX, &y)
    fmt.Printf("%v", err)
}
```

Comment: You're not giving `json.Unamrshal` a concrete type to unmarshal into. It has no way to know what type you want, so it returns an error.

Comment: Aside: you can simplify by writing `var y struct {Status string};`.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. 1) Go doesn't allow overriding at all. 2) UnmarshalJSON isn't used for marshaling JSON. As the name suggests, it's used for unmarshaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot unmarshal into an abstract interface type.
An interface value is just a pointer to a type (associating that types methods) - it has no storage behind it - because an abstract type cannot know the exact size of any concrete value it may have in the future.

Using a concrete value type (that also implements that interface) will work:

```
y2 := emotion{}
err = json.Unmarshal(jsonX, &y2)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8aCEjLgfKVQ

```
MarshalJSON is overriden: I am called fine
EXPECTED ERROR, Can't unmarshal into a non-concrete value: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.Emotion

MarshalJSON is overriden: I am (fixed) and now called
SHOULD NOT ERROR: <nil>
VALUE: happy
```